# Question involving the PDF of a function of a random variable.

Tags: probability, derivatives

I'm trying to understand the setup for problem 3.1, from M.G. Bulmer's *Principles of Statistics* (Dover, 1967).

> Suppose that $X$ is a continuous random variable, and that $Y$ is a linear function of $X$, $Y = a+bX$ where $b$ is positive.  Denote the PDF of $X$ and $Y$ by $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ and the corresponding CDFs by $F(x)$ and $G(y)$, respectively. Then
>
> $$G(y) = Pr(Y\le y) = Pr(a+bX \le y) = Pr(X \le\ \frac{y-a}{b})= Pr(X \le x) = F(\frac{y-a}{b})$$
>
> so
>
> $$g(y) = \frac{dG(y)}{dy} = \frac{1}{b}f(\frac{y-a}{b}) $$

It is stated that "this method can be generalized to find the distribution of any monotonically increasing function of $X$".  The problem is then to find "the distribution" of $X^2$ and $\sqrt X$, if $X$ is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.  (Which I take to mean the PDFs of $X^2$ and $\sqrt X$?, correct?)

I am getting tripped up on the setup.  I believe it is trying to show a method for expressing $G$ of some $value$ in terms of $F$ of some $transform$ of that $value$, where the $transform$ is $\frac{value - a}{b}$.

Then, since the derivative of CDF $G$ with respect to $y$ is PDF $g$, $g$ can be taken to be the derivative of $F(\frac{y-a}{b})$, which I presume is $\frac{1}{b}f(\frac{y-a}{b})$.

What I don't understand is this last step.  How is it that that $\frac{d}{dy}F(\frac{y-a}{b}) = \frac{1}{b}f(\frac{y-a}{b})$ ?

Why is it not just $f(\frac{y-a}{b})$?

i.e., ${dF} = f$, $dCDF= PDF$

Where is the "extra" $\frac{1}{b}$ coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting the chain rule. Note that as shown in your post, $$G(y) = F\left(\dfrac{y-a}{b}\right)$$
and the PDF of $Y$ is given by 
$$G^{\prime}(y) = F^{\prime}\left(\dfrac{y-a}{b}\right)\cdot \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}\left[\dfrac{y-a}{b}\right] = f\left(\dfrac{y-a}{b}\right) \cdot \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{b}}_{\text{pulling out the multiplicative constant}}\cdot \underbrace{\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}\left[y-a\right]}_{1}\text{,}$$
using that $F^{\prime} = f$.

Comment: Thanks @Clarinetist, this is very helpful.